# Uploaded my app but its not visible in Build Tab or Activity Tab

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app around an hour ago and it was successfully uploaded and i got the tick mark. I waited for half hour and nothing happened, no emails , the build wasnt being shown on AppStoreConnect under Builds(testflight) and Activity.

Basically , no traces of what i did. So i tried uploading and i got error that this binary already exists with build number. So i changed the build number and uploaded again , and even now nothing is being shown under builds and under Activity. Also no mails.

Is there something i missed ? Or is there something with AppStoreConnect ?

Under normal circumstances how long do we have to wait? (p.s this is my first app)

Edit: I tried again n it was visible in activity tab for a few mins (PROCESSING). Now its gone and i cant find anything anywhere about it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that there was an error while the binary was being processed (and checked).
Sometimes there are warnings which *should* be fixed and sometimes there are errors. If an error occured, App Store Connect will then stop processing the binary file and send you an email, which contains more details why the app binary was being rejected (automatically).

You should check your email account for additional information.